# Unrecognized selector [MKCircle pointCount] when adding MKCircleOverlay to MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkcircle

I am using Objective C to develop an app for iOS 9.0 and later.

The app includes a view controller with a MKMapView object.  The view controller is the map view delegate.

I am having problems adding a MKCircle overlay in the implementation of viewWillAppear:animated.

Using the `addOverlay:level:` method does not resolve the issue.

The implementation looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.locationCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:self.locationPin.coordinate radius:1000000.0];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.locationCircle];
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]]) {
        MKCircleRenderer *renderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:(MKCircle *)overlay];
        renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25];
        return renderer;
    } else {
        return [self.superclass rendererForOverlay:overlay];
    }
}
```

Specifically, the app is crashing as soon as the map view attempts to show any part of the circle overlay.

The app is successfully rendering polygon overlays and various pin annotations on the map view. The error message details are:

```
2016-11-07 12:35:21.643 [MKCircle pointCount]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000004902c0
2016-11-07 12:35:21.645 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKCircle pointCount]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000004902c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdc334b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c82421e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce32f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd48c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd48798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   MapKit                              0x0000000109af40a3 CreatePathForPolygon.38297 + 57
6   MapKit                              0x0000000109af3e4c -[MKPolygonRenderer createPath] + 128
7   MapKit                              0x0000000109aeefda -[MKOverlayPathRenderer drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:] + 72
8   MapKit                              0x0000000109aefd89 __47-[MKOverlayRenderer overlay:drawKey:inContext:]_block_invoke + 671
9   MapKit                              0x0000000109aefdda _worldsForBounds.37697 + 58
10  MapKit                              0x0000000109aef99f -[MKOverlayRenderer overlay:drawKey:inContext:] + 224
11  VectorKit                           0x00000001170e0534 __40-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource _queueDraw:]_block_invoke + 484
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010de3a980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010de640cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010de43499 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1733
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010de453b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010de4508b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e20d4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e20b341 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Experimenting, I have found that the circle overlay can be added without crashing the app if it is in a part of the map that is not being displayed on the screen.  As soon as the user pans across to the part of the map where the circle is, this crash occurs.

The error occurs when using the simulator with both iOS 10.1 and iOS 9.0.

Any thoughts on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: a radius of `1000000` kilometers seems a little excessive.  do you still have the same problems if you make the radius more human scale (e.g. 10-100 km's?)

Comment: I understood that the radius was in metres.  I have tried though with radii between 1m and the value given and none of them work. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkcircle/1411076-circlewithcentercoordinate

Comment: Yeah, you're right... they are in meters (not sure what I was looking at when  I typed my comment).  The selector that it's looking for comes from [`MKMultiPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmultipoint/1452179-pointcount).

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code and find out exactly which line is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

For swift 4.2. Add following delegate. I am adding Circle and PolyLine to MapView. So need to handle both in delegate.

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKCircle {
      let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
      renderer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
      renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
      renderer.lineWidth = 1
      return renderer
    }
    let polyLine = MKPolylineRenderer.init(overlay: overlay)
    polyLine.strokeColor = UIColor.green
    return polyLine
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for input. The problem in the end was because of an incorrect method signature:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
```

which should have been:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
```

This was not causing wider problems because there was another implementation of the method with the correct signature elsewhere in the code.  That method was trying to treat the MKCircle as a MKPolygon and so was triggering the pointCount problem.